# How Oracle 10g evaluates NULL in boolean expressions

Tags: oracle, null, oracle10g, boolean

```
if not (i_ReLaunch = 1 and (dt_enddate is not null))
```

How  this epression will be evaluated in Oracle 10g
when the input value of the `i_ReLaunch = null` and the value of the `dt_enddate`  is not null
it is entering the loop.
According to the rules in normal c# and all it should not enter the loop as 
it will be as follows with the values.

`If( not(false and (true))
 = if not( false)
=if( true)` which implies it should enters the loop

But it is not happening

Can someone let me know if i am wrong at any place

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Boolean operations with NULL value in Oracle return `UNKNOWN` - not true or false. So you have something like this:

```
If( not(UNKNOWN and (true)) = if not( UNKNOWN) =if( UNKNOWN )
```

In this case, `IF` will treat UNKNOWN as false.

If `i_relaunch` can be null, then you need to use some of NULL handling functions(`NVL, NVL2, NULLIF, COALESCE, LNNVL`)  to be sure that you have correct result.

See these article for more information:

- [Nulls: Nothing to Worry About](http://www.oracle.com/technology/oramag/oracle/05-jul/o45sql.html)
- [Fundamentals of PL/SQL](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/02_funds.htm). Scroll down to  - `Handling Null Values in Comparisons and Conditional Statements`