# null vs empty string in Oracle

Tags: oracle, null, oracle10g, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does Oracle 9i treat an empty string as NULL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203493/why-does-oracle-9i-treat-an-empty-string-as-null)

I have a table in Oracle 10g named `TEMP_TABLE` with only two columns - `id` and `description` just for the sake of demonstration.

The column `id` is a sequence generated primary key of type `NUMBER(35, 0) not null` and the column `DESCRIPTION` is a type of `VARCHAR2(4000) not null`.

The basic table structure in this case would look something like the following.

```
+--------------+-----------+---------------+
|Name          | Null?     | Type          |
+--------------+-----------+---------------+
|ID            | NOT NULL  | NUMBER(35)    |
|DESCRIPTION   | NOT NULL  | VARCHAR2(4000)|
+--------------+-----------+---------------+
```

After creating this table, I'm trying to insert the following `INSERT` commands alternatively.

```
INSERT INTO temp_table (id, description) VALUES (1, null); ->unsuccessful
INSERT INTO temp_table (id, description) VALUES (2, '');   ->unsuccessful
```

Both of them are unsuccessful as obvious because the `not null` constraint is enforced on the `DESCRIPTION` column.

In both of the cases, Oracle complains

```
ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("WAGAFASHIONDB"."TEMP_TABLE"."DESCRIPTION")
```

**An empty string is treated as a `NULL` value in Oracle.**

---

If I dropped the `not null` constraint on the `DESCRIPTION` column then the basic table structure would look like the following

```
+--------------+-----------+---------------+
|Name          | Null?     | Type          |
+--------------+-----------+---------------+
|ID            | NOT NULL  | NUMBER(35)    |
|DESCRIPTION   |           | VARCHAR2(4000)|
+--------------+-----------+---------------+
```

and both of the `INSERT` commands as specified would be successful. They would create two rows one with a `null` value and another with an empty string `''` in the `DESCRIPTION` column of the `TEMP_TABLE`.

Now, if I issue the following `SELECT` command,

```
SELECT * FROM temp_table WHERE description IS NULL;
```

then it fetches both the rows in which one has a `null` value and the other has an empty string `''` in the `DESCRIPTION` column.

The following `SELECT` statement however retrieves no rows from the `TEMP_TABLE`

```
SELECT * FROM temp_table WHERE description='';
```

It doesn't even retrieve the row which has an empty string in the `DESCRIPTION` column.

---

Presumably, it appears that Oracle treats a `null` value and an empty string `''` differently here which however doesn't appear to be the case with the `INSERT` statement in which both a `null` value and an empty string `''` are prevented from being inserted into a column with a `not null` constraint. Why is it so?

Comment: How do you see that there's an empty string in one of the description fields and null in the other?

Comment: @Flansch- Presumably, I assumed with those `INSERT` statements, since I didn't know that empty strings `''` are converted into `null` values, sorry.

Comment: You might want to read [*this*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/203536/1057429)

Answer (score 135, accepted):

This is because Oracle internally changes empty string to NULL values. Oracle simply won't let insert an empty string.

On the other hand, SQL Server would let you do what you are trying to achieve.

There are 2 workarounds here:

1. Use another column that states whether the 'description' field is valid or not
2. Use some dummy value for the 'description' field where you want it to store empty string. (i.e. set the field to be 'stackoverflowrocks' assuming your real data will never encounter such a description value)

Both are, of course, stupid workarounds :)

Comment: Is this the case with string only or with other datatypes as well?

Comment: I did not know that.

Answer (score 36):

In oracle an empty varchar2 and null are treated the same, and your observations show that.

when you write:

```
select * from table where a = '';
```

its the same as writing

```
select * from table where a = null;
```

and not `a is null`

which will never equate to true, so never return a row. same on the insert, a NOT NULL means you cant insert a null or an empty string (which is treated as a null)

Comment: This is particularly interested if you compare 7.3 (without java) and >=8.0 (with java).

Comment: Additionally, the clause `where not(a = '')` also is never true, because `a = ''` is `a = null`, which evaluates to `UNKNOWN`, and `not(UNKNOWN)` is `UNKNOWN`, which is not true. For details on UNKNOWN, see also the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692046/how-oracle-10g-evaluates-null-in-boolean-expressions