# Oracle Turns "" into NULL

Tags: java, oracle, mybatis

I retrieve data from java then insert into Oracle, problem is oracle took `""` values then convert it
into NULL into the table.

this is unwanted behaviour, and it cause problems when I retrieve it from the oracle again, which 
I am expecting a `""` rather than NULL

I prefer a elegant solution setting something on the oracle server side. a global config or something
rather than putting millions of if statements into my Java code.

Comment: Unfortunately [this is how Oracle functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13278773/1134080). You may consider switching to PostgreSQL or MySQL which function differently.

Comment: Well known fact: Oracle *doesn't* have *empty string*, it uses `NULL` instead

Comment: @Pablo most of the questions on this site, explains the same subject with a WHY, I am not looking for why, I am looking for a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in the comments, nothing you can do about it. Oracle treats an empty string no different from NULL and will store NULL into a varchar2 column when you supply it with an empty string.
What you can do if you really want to have something in there, store a single space instead.

Comment: `-` is often clearer that `<space>` but essentially you are correct.

Comment: @ShishirKumar that's just how Oracle works. And historically it's quite correct behaviour. How would the database know whether an empty input field in a Forms application indicates an empty string or no input at all?

Comment: Hey @jwenting, I'm sorry if I offend you. I am aware of this behavior of Oracle. But not comfortable with saving a single space or hyphen or anything when I just want to leave the column blank in first place. I believe this will defeat the idea, not as a whole, of Oracle to save null & empty spaces as same.

Comment: reason I choose this as answer is because saving a single space is the solution. I know its not nice, but at least it shows the value we are expecting it to be there. its not the programmer made this odd situation, its oracle ill defined this function i guess

Comment: I am still uncomfortable with this choice of saving a single space instead of empty strings. Its like I wanted an empty bottle of wine but you give me wine bottle filled with water and I am ok as I can't see the water.

Comment: -1 Avoid magic values (like `'-'`, which may be confused with valid user input). Just use `NULL` like everyone else to represent an empty string.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp you troll, NULL is as much a "magic value" as anything. And I never say to use a hyphen. READ

Comment: Hi jwenting, welcome to SO. We're all friends here, no offence is intended. Now - I agree, NULL is a magic value as well. However, the code to detect it is much simpler than that required to deal with non-standard magic values like `'-'` and `' '`, which may conflict with valid user input. Also, *I* never said *you* suggested the hyphen - you suggested a single space. But, it doesn't matter - both suffer from the same problem. A space is potentially worse, because in some UIs (e.g. SQL*Plus) a space is visually indistinguishable from a NULL.

Answer (score 1):

**An empty string is treated as a null value in Oracle.**

As said above, the **only** solution to differentiate between null values & empty strings is to keep in mind that the `null` value is unique in that you can not use the usual operands (=, <, >, etc) on a null value.

Instead, you must use the `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` conditions to check nulls in Oracle.

Moreover, in order to select the records which has column as empty spaces **but** not empty string and not null, below can be used.

```
WHERE DATALENGTH(COLUMN) > 0
```

And if you want to select any string consisting entirely of spaces as empty.

```
WHERE COLUMN <> ''
```

Hope this helps you.