# Why this code is not going into IF block in PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql, null

I have below PL/SQL code and this is not going into IF block. Why is this not going into the IF Block?

Appreciate your responses.

```
DECLARE
  p_datacenterid VARCHAR2(50) := '';
  p_dcid         VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line('test');
  -- Check if DataCenterId is null
  IF nvl(p_datacenterid, '') = '' THEN
      dbms_output.put_line('DataCenterID is empty');
      SELECT datacenterid
        INTO p_dcid
        FROM pod_tab
       WHERE url = 'dit3.ezlm.adp.com'
         AND rownum = 1;
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PL/SQL and the Oracle database the empty string (`''`) is the same as NULL, and thus you must test for it as you would for NULL by using the `IS NULL` test instead of `= NULL` or `= ''`. Try running the following:

```
declare
  p_DataCenterID   varchar2(50) := '';  -- NOTE: '' is the same as NULL
  p_dcID           varchar2(50);
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line( 'test');

  -- Check if DataCenterId is null

  IF p_DataCenterID IS NULL THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('DataCenterID is empty');

    SELECT DataCenterId
      INTO p_dcID  
      FROM Pod_Tab 
      WHERE URL = 'dit3.ezlm.adp.com' 
        AND ROWNUM = 1;
  END IF;
END;
/
```

This will print

```
test
DataCenterID is empty
```

Best of luck.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you are getting tripped up on comparing null values.  An empty string is converted by Oracle into Null in the background.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13278879/851930) for details.

The IF statement ends up resolving to IF null = null which is never true.

Something like this would work

```
IF p_DataCenterID  IS NOT NULL  THEN
   --assert the values are within a range
ELSE
   --look up the value
END IF;
```

Comment: I tried the above IF also. Still not going into IF LOOP.

Comment: You don't have a loop in  your code @Rita... so it's not really clear what you're asking. As Bob demonstrates below this answer works... so you're going to have to be more specific about what is incorrect.