# Null values are getting inserted in database

Tags: java, jdbc

I am checking that submitted data is not null but on simply submitting(no data) it is still inserting in the database and also i have made my columns not null but data is still getting inserted.I don't know why?

IN my Servlet

```
try{
        String department=request.getParameter("department");
        String company=request.getParameter("company");
        String place=request.getParameter("place");
        boolean checkd=checknull.value(department);
        boolean checkc=checknull.value(company);
        boolean checkp=checknull.value(place);
        if(checkd==true&&checkc==true&&checkp==true) {
        Connection con=ConnectionProvider.getCon();
        String sql="insert into department(departmentname,company,place) values (?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement pstmt =con.prepareStatement(sql);

        pstmt.setString(1,department); 
        pstmt.setString(2,company);
        pstmt.setString(3,place);
        int rs=pstmt.executeUpdate();
        if(rs>0){status=true;}

            if(status){
                  PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();
                  out.print("values have been inserted,"+admin);
                  response.sendRedirect("inserted.jsp");
                        }
              else 
              {   
                  PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();
                  out.print("failed to insert");
                  response.sendRedirect("notinsered.jsp");
              }
            }
        else{response.sendRedirect("entry.jsp");}
            }catch(SQLException e){}
```

This is the java class which is checking

```
public class checknull {  
static boolean ch;    
public static boolean value(String check)
{           
    ch = check != null;
    return ch;
}
```

Comment: The values from the form might be empty string.

Comment: how should i check for empty string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your `checknull` class to:

```
public class checknull
{
    // static boolean ch; (You don't need this static variable)
    public static boolean value(String check)
    {
       return check != null && check.length() > 0;
    }
}
```

Also, it's a convention in Java to have class names in `UpperCase`.

**Example**:

```
public class CheckNull
```

**EDIT**:
As suggested by [Erwin Bolwidt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/981744/erwin-bolwidt), it's very likely that the database being used here is Oracle, since Oracle equates empty strings and nulls.

Therefore, this answer is only applicable to databases that treat empty strings as nulls (e.g. Oracle).

See: [null-vs-empty-string-in-oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278773/null-vs-empty-string-in-oracle)

Comment: Why should he include the check on string length? How does that affect nulls in the database?

Comment: Nulls weren't going into the database, empty strings were.

Comment: If he gets null out like he says, and it happens when he puts empty strings in, then he must be using Oracle. I think that's the only database that equates them. Which also means that your answer only works for Oracle. That's probably helpful to add for future readers.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I updated my answer to include your feedback. Thank you.