# Import in Oracle from .sql and .unl files result from Informix dbexport

Tags: database, oracle, migration, informix

I made a dbexport from Informix database and I have the `.sql` and `.unl` files.
Can I recreate the exported database into Oracle from the files?

If not is possible, is there any RDBMS that can do it?

Comment: I don't know what facilities Oracle provides, but it is likely there's an off-the-shelf solution to import such data.  However, the issue you face include: (1) Data format — pipe-separated fields is probably not the default in Oracle; (2) Data types — you may be using types in Informix without a good analogue in Oracle; (3) SQL syntax — you may be using features of Informix that Oracle doesn't support; (4) Stored procedures — Informix SPL (stored procedure language) is very different from Oracle's, so transferring stored procedures may be tricky.

Comment: You'll need to review the `.sql` file and the `.unl` files (mostly the `.sql` file) to see the scope of the problems you face.

Answer (score 0):

As Jonathan wrote in comment it will not be easy. Files created by Informix dbexport are not directly usable by other databases. But while this is easy to read text information you can write program that converts both `.sql` and `.uml` files into files usable to your preferred database. If you use stored procedures then it is really hard.

For table definitions in `CREATE TABLE ...` you will have to convert Informix types like `DATETIME YEAR TO DAY` to `DATE`, or `SERIAL` into `INTEGER`. Oracle have no `SERIAL` type so you will have to create sequence and trigger for such columns.

When you convert db schema you can import data from `.unl` files. I suggest to write your own program that reads it as CSV data, make PrepareStatement with `INSERT` and converts some data. Also remember that Oracle do not use empty strings: [null vs empty string in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278773/null-vs-empty-string-in-oracle)

Comment: Fortunatelly I don't have any stored procedure, I only have database base definition and data. To solve the problems of data types that Jonathan points, I think that replacing in the sql file those types for the corrects in Oracle would be a solution.