# How to convert blank to NULL in oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have blanks in my name column in sql query. How can I replace to show as `null`.

```
SELECT Name from table
```

Comment: You can use `LTRIM(RTRIM(Name))`.

Comment: Can you define a "blank"? What does this mean? When you say you want to show as null do you mean demonstrate non-existence or literally the string `'null'`?

Comment: @Ben  - blank means blank space...I would like to show the string null

Answer (score 2):

The [`TRIM` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions199.htm) provides this feature.

It is used like this:

```
select TRIM(Name) from table
```

It will remove leading and trailing spaces from the results for field `Name`.

Comment: An empty string `''` and a null are equivalent in Oracle when the data type is a (N)VARCHAR or a (N)VARCHAR2. This won't do anything: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278773/null-vs-empty-string-in-oracle

Comment: @Ben Did not know that. Then `TRIM` should suffice. I changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: Depending on your client application it may display null in different ways. To ensure that you always see the string 'null' wrap the TRIM in a NVL displaying 'null' when the trimmed name is null.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are talking of spaces?

Here is how to remove any commonly known "blank" chars:

- with `regexp_replace` (interestingly... just to notice the `[[:space:]]`)

---

```
select '<'||
  regexp_replace(
   'a'||CHR(9)||' b'||CHR(10)||CHR(11)
      ||'c'||CHR(12)||CHR(13)||' d'
 , '[[:space:]]','')
||'>' 
from dual;
```

- more efficient: avoid `regexp_replace`...: use `TRANSLATE`!

---

```
select '<'||
  TRANSLATE(
   'a'||CHR(9)||' b'||CHR(10)||CHR(11)
      ||'c'||CHR(12)||CHR(13)||' d' -- complicate string with blank
  ,'A'||CHR(9)||CHR(10)||CHR(11)||CHR(12)||CHR(13)||' '
  ,'A') -- this 'A' is a trick to replace by null ('')
||'>'    -- to show where string stops
from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

`TRIM` removes the blank character from left and right, so if your string only consists of blanks then you get an empty string, which is NULL in Oracle.

```
select trim(name) from mytable;
```

This would also change `'  Mary Smith  '` to `'Mary Smith'`, but I guess you wouldn't mind :-)

If, however, you want to consider any whitespace, e.g. tabs, too, then `TRIM` doesn't suffice. You can use `REGEXP_REPLACE` then to replace all names that only consist of whitespace with null.

```
regexp_replace(name, '^[[:space:]]*$', null) from mytable;
```

If you also want to trim whitespace from any names (so `'  Mary Smith  '` becomes `'Mary Smith'` again) then:

```
select regexp_replace(name, '^[[:space:]]*([^[:space:]]*)[[:space:]]*', '\1') from mytable;
```